# Vue3, Vuex does not update DOM element

Tags: javascript, vuex, vuejs3

I'm trying to make a simple counter application by using Vue3 and Vuex.
It may be a simple question because I'm new at Vue.

I checked that Vuex mutation is working by Vue dev tools and also by console.
It increases counter when I click the increase button.
But, I can't find the reason why my DOM is not updating.

Any simple answer would be a great help for me

**Directories**
[image: my directory]

---

**This is my code**

```
// App.vue
<template>
  <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">
  <div class="counter">
    {{$store.state.counter}}
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button @click="increment">+</button>
    <button @click="decrement">-</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import {mapState} from 'vuex'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  data() {
    return {
      // counter: 0
    }
  },
  methods: {
    increment() {
      this.$store.commit('increment')
    },
    decrement() {
      this.$store.commit('decrement')
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState(['counter'])
    // counter() {
    //   // return this.$store.state.counter
      
    // }
  }
}
</script>
```

```
// main.js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import store from './store/index'

createApp(App).use(store).mount('#app')
```

```
// store/index.js
import { createStore } from 'vuex'

export default createStore({
  state: {
    counter: 0
  },
  mutations: {
    increment(state) {
      state.counter++
      console.log(state.counter)
    },
    decrement(state) {
      state.counter--
      console.log(state.counter)
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: I don't know Vue, but I would guess the change detection works in an immutable way, so changing `state.counter++` to `state.counter = state.counter + 1` could perhaps solve it.

Comment: Did you try using just `{{ counter }}` instead of `{{$store.state.counter}}` ?

Comment: @DanielB Tried it, but it gives me same result :( doesn't update DOM

Comment: @IVOGELOV Tried it, but same result :( doesn't update DOM

Comment: @HJKim what is the value of `this.counter` in the increment or decrement method?

Comment: @Matt If i `console.log(this.counter)` in method(App.vue), it keep prints 0. The counter value doesn't change. Still, I can see that value is changing by devtools. But, if i `console.log(state.counter)` in mutations(index.js), counter value changes. It increases and decreases by clicking buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess it was problem with Vue3.
I installed vuex alpha version, and it works on my local computer.

```
npm i vuex@4.0.0-alpha.1
```